# Where can I find an example or tutorial, suitable for a beginner, on incorporating a three.js animation into a web app?

Tags: javascript, animation, web-applications, three.js, webgl

I'm a student wanting to make a web app/web site as a project, with an interactive three.js animation incorporated into it.

I've found enough information on learning three.js and useful examples which are either animations or games. But I can't find either an example or tutorial at a beginners level, that uses a three.js animation as part of something like a product selection website.

For example, a car website. Customers can select different wheels on the car, different accessories and color. Once picked they can play the animation of the car moving. I will stress that I'm looking for something basic, so that I can go in and understand the code without too much expert knowledge. Or a beginners tutorial.

Any kind of three.js example or tutorial on a user choices (from a panel that I could build/customize) changing the animation would be welcome.

I believe this information would be useful to many three.js beginners as the issue is raised in the O'Reilly book by Tony Parisi. To solve this he has created a framework built on three.js called Vizi https://github.com/tparisi/Vizi. However it's very new (March 2014) and in beta.

Thanks for any help; first time poster.

Comment: stackoverflow isn't really the appropiate place for this kind of question: See #5 on this page (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You can find simpler examples at http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/, although the examples may be based on an older version of the library.

Comment: Sorry if this is too general a question for stackoverflow, I ask here because there is no three.js forum and I've been directed here to ask questions.

Comment: I've seen those good examples at stemkoski, none of them answer the question of how to use an animation in a webpage, not be the webpage itself. Thanks though :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well the scenario with the car you're describing is not simple at all. I coded a similar scenario for wedding rings, and a friend of mine is working on something like this for watches. These are rather large projects because what you want is customizeable 3D objects. They first need to be designed and coded.
In your car case you'd maybe have to create all the wheels in Blender, create the car, stitch them together in THREE.js, have a GUI where you can swap out wheels and where the selected wheel gets exchanged on the car. And there's a lot more to it...

If you're looking for something like JqueryUI for 3D then I'm afraid that doesn't exist (yet?) since 3D is usually a tad more complicated...

I haven't hear of Vizi yet but maybe it helps your case, who knows. Other than that there's software where you can embed a model or scene into your website, but without the fancy wheel exchanging stuff. http://clara.io/ and http://verold.com/ are some, maybe have a look if it's something you can work with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Doidel. I've had a look at Verold and Clara.io which are good for non interactive rendering at the moment. Unfortunately I'm committed to having some form of user interaction for my project. After I researching WebGL and ThreeJS I realised it would be a big project. So I'm only doing a basic app, only in Google Chrome, no mobile, 2D fallback etc. I'm just trying to find out how integrate a simple (customizable) GUI that will change a ThreeJS variable on click. It's the communication between the GUI and ThreeJS that I don't know where to start with. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah well if it's just that then you might use "dat.gui". It's used in many three.js projects and examples, and it lets you set up a default GUI for some three.js variables. I use it here for example: http://lizkats.com/levelEditor/

Comment: Thanks Doidel, that looks like the perfect place to start for me :-)

Comment: You can create interactive experiences using Clara.io as well very easily because Clara.io can interact with jQuery in the rest of the web page to change cameras, materials, etc.  Here is a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZiXyji2JH0  Let me know if you need any help: ben@clara.io